# C# generics with MVVM, pulling the T out of <T>

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm

My `Model` is a generic class that contains a (for example) `Value` property which can be int, float, string, bool, etc. So naturally this class is represented something like `Model<T>`. For the sake of collections `Model<T>` implements the interface `IModel`, although `IModel` is itself empty of any content.

My `ViewModel` contains and instance of `Model<T>` and it is passed in through `ViewModel`'s constructor. I still want to know what `T` is in ViewModel, so when I expose `Model` to the `View` I know the datatype of `Model`'s buried `Value` property. The class for ViewModel ends up looking like the following:

```
class ViewModel<T>
{
   private Model<T> _model;

   public ViewModel(Model<T> model) { ....blah.... }

   public T ModelsValue {get; set; }

}
```

This works fine, but is limited. So now I need to expose a collection of `IModels` with varying `Ts` to my `View`, so I'm trying to set up an `ObservableCollection` of `new ViewModel<T>s` to a changing list of `IModels`. The problem is, I can't figure out how to get `T` from `Model<T>` from `IModel` to construct `ViewModel<T>(Model<T>)` at runtime.

In the VS2010 debugger I can mouseover any `IModel` object and see its full `Model<int>` for example at runtime so I know the data is in there.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to over architect something which must be simple, besides there's no way in .Net to statically aggregate different types IE: ViewModel<T1, T2, T3 ... Tn>.

Comment: Pop, I am open to hearing fundamentally different design approaches as well. Fire away!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I'm using for view model collections:

### Preface:

Your view model objects can be weakly typed. Give `IModel` a property `object Value {get;}` and expose that in a `ModelViewModel : ViewModel<IModel>` that you use for all `IModel` objects (see my `ViewModel<T>` implementation below). If you have various combinations of `ObservableCollection<IModel>`, `ICollection<Model<T>>`, etc., the framework shown here is a lifesaver. If you still need generic view model, you can derive a `ModelViewModel<T> : ModelViewModel` that takes a `Model<T>` in its constructor. The logic to create the appropriate type would go in the converter passed to `ViewModelCollection.Create` below. *Do be warned that this design will impose a performance penalty.*

```
ModelViewModel CreateModelViewModel(IModel model)
{
    Type viewModelType = typeof(ModelViewModel<>).MakeGenericType(model.Type);
    ModelViewModel viewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelType, model);
    return viewModel;
}
```

### Example usage:

```
public class CatalogViewModel : ViewModel<ICatalog>
{
    public CatalogViewModel(ICatalog catalog)
        : base(catalog)
    {
        Func<ICatalogProduct, ProductViewModel> viewModelFactory = CreateProductViewModel;

        this.Products = ViewModelCollection.Create(catalog.Products, viewModelFactory);
    }

    public ICollection<ProductViewModel> Products
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private ProductViewModel CreateProductViewModel(ICatalogProduct product)
    {
        return new ProductViewModel(product, this);
    }
}
```

### Benefits:

- Uses lazy implementations to allow for efficient and even recursive bindings in trees.
- The view model collections only implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` if the underlying model collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

### Overview of the classes (full implementations linked to github):

- [**`ViewModel<TModel>`**](http://github.com/280Z28/Application-Foundations/blob/master/Mvvm/ViewModel%601.cs): Base class for my view model classes. Exposes a `Model` property that I use in the view model's backing code.
- [**`ObservableViewModelCollection<TViewModel, TModel>`**](http://github.com/280Z28/Application-Foundations/blob/master/Mvvm/ObservableViewModelCollection%602.cs): **Lazy** (actually not currently, but definitely should be), **observable** mapping from a model to a view model. Implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.
- [**`ViewModelCollection<TViewModel, TModel>`**](http://github.com/280Z28/Application-Foundations/blob/master/Mvvm/ViewModelCollection%602.cs): **Lazy** mapping from a collection of TModel to a collection of `TViewModel`.
- [**`ViewModelCollection`**](http://github.com/280Z28/Application-Foundations/blob/master/Mvvm/ViewModelCollection.cs): Static helper - returns an `ICollection<TViewModel>`, using `ObservableViewModelCollection<TViewModel, TModel>` when the source collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, otherwise using `ViewModelCollection<TViewModel, TModel>`.

### A few extra types that might be useful for your view model collections:

`ConcatCollection`: Like ViewModelCollection, this includes a static helper to automatically choose an appropriate implementation. The ConcatCollection concatenates collections by binding directly to the source collection(s).

- [`ConcatCollection`](http://github.com/280Z28/Application-Foundations/blob/master/Mvvm/ConcatCollection.cs)
- [`ConcatCollection<T>`](http://github.com/280Z28/Application-Foundations/blob/master/Mvvm/ConcatCollection%601.cs)
- [`ObservableConcatCollection<T>`](http://github.com/280Z28/Application-Foundations/blob/master/Mvvm/ObservableConcatCollection%601.cs)

Here is an example of how I used this type to expose a `Children` property to the view while maintaining my observable collections all the way to back to the original source.

```
public class ProductViewModel : ViewModel<IProduct>
{
    public ProductViewModel(IProduct product)
        : base(product)
    {
        Func<IProduct, ProductViewModel> productViewModelFactory = CreateProductViewModel;
        Func<IRelease, ReleaseViewModel> releaseViewModelFactory = CreateReleaseViewModel;

        this.Products = ViewModelCollection.Create(product.Products, productViewModelFactory);
        this.Releases = ViewModelCollection.Create(product.Releases, releaseViewModelFactory);
        this.Children = ConcatCollection.Create<object>((ICollection)this.Products, (ICollection)this.Releases);
    }

    public IList<ProductViewModel> Products
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IList<ReleaseViewModel> Releases
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> Children
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private ProductViewModel CreateProductViewModel(IProduct product)
    {
        return new ProductViewModel(product);
    }

    private ReleaseViewModel CreateReleaseViewModel(IRelease release)
    {
        return new ReleaseViewModel(release);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, when you said:

> When I expose `Model` to the `View`

You aren't following MVVM conventions, for whatever that's worth. In MVVM, the model itself should never be exposed to the view.

That being said, you can expose the type of `T` in this way.

```
public Type ModelType
{
    get { return typeof(T); }
}
```

If that suits your purposes.

Comment: This works to get the type, but I cannot call ModelView<model.ModelType>(model); that won't compile.

Comment: Also, about your side note, I don't expose my model -- I wrote it that way for code simplicity.

Comment: *"In MVVM, the model itself should never be exposed to the view."* - otherwise, the MVVM police will take away your family, as [Laurent Bugnion](http://www.galasoft.ch/) would say (ironically)... Of course, you can expose the model to the view, it is your personal decision. MVVM is just a pattern, and patterns are ideas, and ideas can be modified. Anyway, I do not want to start a decision about that here because it would be off-topic.

Comment: @gehho: Of course you can expose your model to the view. The point of my statement is that *doing so means you aren't using MVVM*. If you didn't want to start a discussion, why bring it up?

Comment: @Adam: No offense intended, really, but I just do not like it if people claim that MVVM does not allow to 1) have a Model property in the VM, 2) have a reference to the View in the VM, 3) whatever else - just because *it confuses people*. I am not aware of an ISO standard for MVVM defining all the details. Furthermore, *a lot of people* use a Model property, e.g. Karl Shifflett obviously does so, as you can see in the graphic in [this blog post](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mvvm/wpf-line-of-business-introduction/). End note: MVVM is a concept, but not a law.

Comment: @gehho: No offense taken, but it seems rather silly to say "I don't want to start a discussion" after hijacking someone else's answer. It essentially says "I want to say my piece, but I don't want anyone to respond to it." Nobody says that you cannot expose the model, *just that the design philosophy behind MVVM says that you shouldn't.*. It's the entire *point* of MVVM to hide the model from the view, and *make the view's model the **viewmodel**.* End note: if you don't want to start a discussion, don't comment.

Comment: *"I want to say my piece, but I don't want anyone to respond to it."* Actually, that was about my intention, yes, just without that negative connotation. The reason for my comment was to let an unexperienced reader know that - in certain situations - it might be absolutely fine to have a Model property in the VM. Now, I am perfectly fine. :)

Comment: @gehho: It's absolutely fine to do so, it just isn't following MVVM conventions. Hence my pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be to have an interface `IModelValue` that would expose T from `Model<T>`. Then your ViewModel class would look like:

```
class ViewModel
{
   private IModel _model;

   public ViewModel(IModel model) { ....blah.... }

   public IModelValue ModelsValue {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# generics won't allow generic type as type parameter:

```
ObservableCollection<ViewModel<T>>
```

Above is not only illegal in C#, but also makes no sense because it would break static type constraints.

I'm guessing what you **really** are trying to do is:

```
class ViewModel<T> : IMyViewModel {...}

new ObservableCollection<IMyViewModel>()
```

than you need some kind of factory that would produce IMyViewModel instances based on IModel runtime type:

```
public IMyViewModel CreateMyViewModel( IModel model){
    if (model is Model<A>)
        return new ViewModel(model as Model<A>);
    if (model is Model<B>)
        return new ViewModel(model as Model<B>);
    ...etc..
}
```

thus, having a

```
IEnumarable<IModel> models = ...
```

you can get

```
var myVMs = 
    from m in models select CreateMyViewModel(m);

myCollection = new ObservableCollection<IMyViewModel>(myVMs);
```

Comment: If the object in `myCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (as does `ObservableCollection<T>`), it implies that the collection sends notifications when the source data changes. In the case you gave, it doesn't - misuse of this type leaves the developer with no way to tell whether the UI should use polling or events to update the view.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, why it doesn't send notifications? Where is the misuse?