# Create ViewModel with generic parmater

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern and i am trying to create generic dialogue box to import data using xml file.

So, all what i need is to pass T object to data service to get the view settings and to do the converting logic from XML file and return to me list of object in view setting.

For example,i create Data Services look like below:

```
public class CategoryHierarchyFileImportDataService: ICategoryHierarchyFileImportDataService
    {
    #region Public Methods

    public virtual CategoryHierarchyFileImportViewSettings<T> GetCategoryHierarchyFileImportViewSettings<T>()
    {
        var result = _mappingEngine.Map<List<ApplicationObjectDTO>, CategoryHierarchyFileImportViewSettings<T>>(_viewApplicationObjects[ViewNames.CategoryHierarchyFileImportView]);
        result.DocumentProperties.Caption = result.ListCaptionLabelContent;

        return result;
    }}
```

So i want to create the view model like this:

```
    public class CategoryHierarchyFileImportViewModel<T> : BindableBase, IPopUpViewModel
{
    #region Private Variables

    private readonly ICategoryHierarchyFileImportDataService _categoryHierarchyFileImportDataService;
    private readonly IOpenFileDialogWrapperService _openFileDialogWrapper;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public DelegateCommand BrowseFilesCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand ImportCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand CancelCommand { get; set; }
    public CategoryHierarchyFileImportViewSettings<T> ViewSettings { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors


    public CategoryHierarchyFileImportViewModel(
        ICategoryHierarchyFileImportDataService categoryHierarchyFileImportDataService,
        IApplicationObjectDataService applicationObjectDataService,
        IOpenFileDialogWrapperService openFileDialogWrapper)
    {
        _categoryHierarchyFileImportDataService = categoryHierarchyFileImportDataService;
        _openFileDialogWrapper = openFileDialogWrapper;
        applicationObjectDataService.LoadApplicationObjects(ViewNames.CategoryHierarchyFileImportView);
        ImportCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteImportCommand);
        CancelCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteCancelCommand);
        BrowseFilesCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteBrowseFilesCommand);
        ViewSettings = _categoryHierarchyFileImportDataService.GetCategoryHierarchyFileImportViewSettings<T>();
    }
}
```

But the problem i am unable to create the view model like this as the View will complain and i will not be able to bind view model.

So can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Wrap your ViewModel by non-generic class, [here][1] is a direction


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698910/c-sharp-generics-with-mvvm-pulling-the-t-out-of-t

Comment: So, how i pass T to dataservice ?! I am not just using T in viewmodel but i pass it to dataservice